# Git post-receive script hangs indefinitely

Tags: bash, git, shell, ssh

I have a remote machine which I use ssh to connect to.
I have configured an empty git repo on it with `git init --bare` and made the working tree be a folder called test.
Then, I configured the machine locally so I can use git push to push branches to it.
This whole process alone works fine.
The problem is - I have a post-receive script which executes a few commands (including a shell script) and no matter which commands I put there, after a git push to that remote machine, after the post-receive gets executed (and it does get executed successfully, at least it seems so) my git bash which I used to `git push` hangs forever until I do CTRL+C...
What could be causing this?

Comment: How did you verify that your post-receive script really runs to its end?

Answer (score 0):

Try with a simple hook, named `post-receive` (no extension, set in your `bare repo folder/.hooks`) and make sure it is executable.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "my post-receive hook"
exit 0
```

> including a shell script

As [mentioned here](https://serverfault.com/a/954381/783), depending on how your post-receive hook is calling that shell script, Git might  wait for all the children processes left over by said post-receive hook.